# According to Full Preterists, what historical facts fulfilled the signs and wonders prophesied by Paul in 2 Thessalonians 2:9?

Tags: exegesis, history, eschatology, preterism, 2-thessalonians

2 Thessalonians 2:1-12 (ESV):

> Now concerning the coming of our Lord Jesus Christ and our being gathered together to him, we ask you, brothers, 2 not to be quickly shaken in mind or alarmed, either by a spirit or a spoken word, or a letter seeming to be from us, to the effect that the day of the Lord has come. 3 Let no one deceive you in any way. For that day will not come, unless the rebellion comes first, and the man of lawlessness is revealed, the son of destruction, 4 who opposes and exalts himself against every so-called god or object of worship, so that he takes his seat in the temple of God, proclaiming himself to be God. 5 Do you not remember that when I was still with you I told you these things? 6 And you know what is restraining him now so that he may be revealed in his time. 7 For the mystery of lawlessness is already at work. Only he who now restrains it will do so until he is out of the way. 8 And then the lawless one will be revealed, whom the Lord Jesus will kill with the breath of his mouth and bring to nothing by the appearance of his coming. 9 **The coming of the lawless one is by the activity of Satan with all power and false signs and wonders**, 10 and with all wicked deception for those who are perishing, because they refused to love the truth and so be saved. 11 Therefore God sends them a strong delusion, so that they may believe what is false, 12 in order that all may be condemned who did not believe the truth but had pleasure in unrighteousness.

According to Full Preterists, what historical facts fulfilled the false signs and wonders prophesied by the apostle Paul in 2 Thessalonians 2:9?

---

Relevant related question on Hermeneutics: [What signs and wonders are performed by whom? 2 Thessalonians 2:9-10](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/62523/what-signs-and-wonders-are-performed-by-whom-2-thessalonians-29-10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.revelationrevolution.org/2-thessalonians-2-1-9-a-preterist-commentary-the-man-of-lawlessness-revealed/

The full preterist site above claims Vespasian and his son Titus Fulfilled these prophecies.

> Preterism Explained and Interpreted, A Commentary of 2 Thessalonians
> 2:9: Around the Time in Which Titus Arrived in Jerusalem to Beseiege
> the City and Immediately before Vespasian became Emperor, “All Kinds
> of Counterfeit Miracles, Signs and Wonders” were Reported.
>
> Before making
> His Triumphal Entry into Rome, Vespasian, the Man of Lawlessness,
> Miraculously healed a Blind Man and a Lame Man or a Man with a
> Withered Hand.
>
> There were
> also Miraculous Signs that Accompanied Titus’ Return to Israel to
> Besiege Jerusalem in A.D. 70 as well as His Coming to Rome afterwards
> to Celebrate the Triumph with His Father, Vespasian.
>
> At around the Time that His Father Healed the Two Men, Titus called
> down Fire from Heaven in a Counterfeit Miracle.

At the end of the article, the author summarizes.

> The two miracles performed by or illustrated through Caesar Titus
> during the destruction of the Temple–like the miracles performed by
> his father, Vespasian–are also counterfeit because Titus did not
> literally call fire down from heaven nor did he literally rise from
> the dead.